# Why Heroku redirect my site on HTTPS with no SSL setup?

Tags: django, ssl, heroku, deployment

I've deploy my django website on heroku. After adding my custom domain, when i try to access to http://www.example.com it redirect me to https://www.example.com and i get this message

```
ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT
```

I haven't add any SSL certificate, is it normal that i'm redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: No, Heroku doesn't do this for you. Do you have [`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT) enabled?

Comment: I have 'SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False' in my settings.py

Comment: I just notice that i have the 'ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT' error only on google chrome. Is the problem from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, that your browser redirects you to `https`, not Heroku. Try to use Google Chrome in guest mode or some other browser.

Also, you can check response of your site via python package `requests` or smth. It should return 200 code if your site works correctly.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
print(f"{resp.status_code=}")
```

Comment: I have clear all the browsing datas in google chrome and now i can access to it via http. Do you know what caused this trouble?

Comment: maybe because of [http redirect cache](https://www.ryadel.com/en/clear-http-https-redirect-cache-hsts-settings-google-chrome-mozilla-firefox/)